# X-Frame-Options in nginx to allow all domains

Tags: nginx, iframe, server, x-frame-options, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using `nginx` as a reverse proxy for my website.

I want to be able to open my website in an `iFrame` from a chrome extension new tab html file.

For this, I need my `nginx` to set `X-Frame-Options` to allow **all** domains.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44436783/3765646), all domains is the default state if you don't set X-Frame-Options.

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` doesn't have the X-Frame-Options set anywhere.

Yet when I check my website response header using Postman, it shows me `X-Frame-Options = SAMEORIGIN`.

How can I remove this setting and load my website in an iFrame in the chrome new-tab .html file?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Solved it by changing proxy_hide_header values in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file like so:

```
proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
```

Needed to restart `nginx` as well as use `pm2` to restart my `nodejs` server (for some reason, it didn't work till I made a small change to my server and restarted it).

Comment: Wish this was better documented though.

Comment: I did that though not in default in the app-specific conf file and it didn't work.

I have Cloudflare in front of the server, does that overwrite the header in anyway?

Answer (score 20):

`add_header X-Frame-Options "";` did the trick for me in nginx 1.12.

Answer (score 10):

Found this header in `/etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf`

Just needed to comment out the line:

```
# add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
```

Comment: I have nginx 1.18 configured w/ SSL and this did the trick for me. I was getting irritated at all the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I found this header option in the file /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.

```
add_header  X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
```

default.conf file is mentioned in my main nginx.conf file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have added in /etc/nginx/sites-available/app file (ubuntu 18.04). It works. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 2):

Add into nginx server blocks here if you have different websites on your server, to control at domain level, no main nginx config changes needed

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_buffering on;# important - set as off for WSL dev environment
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
            include fastcgi_params;
```

### ALLOW IFRAMES

```
            add_header X-Frame-Options "" always;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try adding this in your nginx config

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "" always;
```

it works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).